# SAS Web App Server SASServer6_1 is still in the process of starting up, proceeding with additional servers

Tags: spring, sas

После установки HotFix  с помощью SASHFADD, не взлетает веб интерфейс SAS CIS

В логах SASCustIntelCore6.6.log вижу следящую ошибку:

> **WARN**  [localhost-startStop-1] [] []
> context.support.XmlWebApplicationContext - Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name
> 'com.sas.svcs.cache.cacheableBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path
> resource [com/sas/svcs/data/caches/gemfire/sas_gemfire_config.xml]:
> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sas_gemfire_cache' while setting
> bean property 'cache'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'sas_gemfire_cache': FactoryBean threw
> exception on object creation; nested exception is
> com.gemstone.gemfire.GemFireConfigException: Unable to contact a
> Locator service.  Operation either timed out or Locator does not
> exist.  Configured list of locators is
> "[test-mid(null):41415]".
>
> **ERROR** [localhost-startStop-1] [] []
> pringframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization
> failed org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name
> 'com.sas.svcs.cache.cacheableBeanPostProcessor' defined in class path
> resource [com/sas/svcs/data/caches/gemfire/sas_gemfire_config.xml]:
> Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sas_gemfire_cache' while setting
> bean property 'cache'; nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'sas_gemfire_cache': FactoryBean threw
> exception on object creation; nested exception is
> com.gemstone.gemfire.GemFireConfigException: Unable to contact a
> Locator service.  Operation either timed out or Locator does not
> exist.  Configured list of locators is "[test-mid(null):41415]".
> at
>
> at
> com.sas.svcs.webapp.servlet.springframework.DefaultContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(DefaultContextLoaderListener.java:44)
> at
> org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4701)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) Caused by:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
> creating bean with name 'sas_gemfire_cache': FactoryBean threw
> exception on object creation; nested exception is
> com.gemstone.gemfire.GemFireConfigException: Unable to contact a
> Locator service.  Operation either timed out or Locator does not
> exist.  Configured list of locators is
> "[stl-test-mid(null):41415]".     at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.doGetObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:173)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.getObjectFromFactoryBean(FactoryBeanRegistrySupport.java:102)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:191)
> at
> org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
> ... 28 more Caused by: com.gemstone.gemfire.GemFireConfigException:
> Unable to contact a Locator service.  Operation either timed out or
> Locator does not exist.  Configured list of locators is
> "[stl-test-mid(null):41415]".     at
> com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.TCPGOSSIP.sendGetMembersRequest(TCPGOSSIP.java:222)
> at
> com.gemstone.org.jgroups.protocols.PingSender.run(PingSender.java:85)
> ... 1 more
> **DEBUG** [localhost-startStop-1] [] [] .crm.spring.client.SASEnvironmentFactory - Unable to lookup
> ServiceRegistry in serviceURL DAO.
> **DEBUG** [localhost-startStop-1] [] [] .crm.spring.client.SASEnvironmentFactory - Using service registry
> defaultValue

В логе gemfire.log:

> [warning   
> tid=0x16] org/springframework/util/StringUtils
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/util/StringUtils
> at
> org.springframework.shell.core.Completion.(Completion.java:50)
> at
> org.springframework.shell.core.Completion.(Completion.java:35)
> at
> com.gemstone.gemfire.management.internal.cli.converters.LogLevelConverter.(LogLevelConverter.java:34)
> at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native
> Method)   at
> sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at
> at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
> at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)

При установке хот фиксов соблюдались инструкции из документации к исправлениям, пост-инсталляционные работы также выполнены.
Служба безопасности была обновлена до 12 версии

В чём может быть причина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)